# Elliptic Eigenproblem in 2D

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, multivariable-calculus

Let $\Omega$ be the open Euclidean unit disk in $\mathbb{R}^2$. I wish to solve the eigenproblem

> $$
>  -\nabla^2u=\lambda u \mbox{ in } \Omega,\\ u=0 \mbox{ on } \partial\Omega. $$

Using polar coordinates and separation of variables, we let $u(r,\theta)=R(r)H(\theta)$. Then, the boundary condition tells us that for all $\theta$,
$$u(1,\theta)=R(1)H(\theta)=0.$$
And the first equation tells us that in $\Omega$,

$$\frac{H}{r}\frac{d}{dr}(rR')+\frac{R}{r^2}H''=-\lambda H R.$$
Rearranging gives, for an appropriate separation constant $c$,
$$\frac{r\left(\lambda R + \frac{d}{dr}(rR')\right)}{R}=\frac{-H''}{H}=c.$$
This gives us the two equations
$$r^2R'' +rR'+(\lambda r^2-c)R=0,\\
H''+cH=0.$$

Now, I'm not entirely sure what to do...

Answer (score 1):

Since for all $\theta$, $R(1)H(\theta)=0$, $H$ must be bounded. Also, we will write $\lambda=k^2$ for some $k>0$ so that the differential equation in $R$ is a Bessel equation with parameter $k$.

Suppose $c=-\omega^2$ for some $\omega>0$. Then, $H=a_1\sinh(\omega\theta) + a_2\cosh(\omega\theta)$ for some constants $a_1,a_2$. However, neither $\sinh$ nor $\cosh$ are bounded, so we may throw this case out.

Suppose $c=0$. Then, $H=a_1\theta+a_2$ for some constants $a_1,a_2$. However, $a_1=0$ in order for $H$ to be bounded, so $H$ is just some constant function. Furthermore, $R=b_1J_0(kr) + b_2Y_0(kr)$ for some constants $b_1,b_2$. However, $Y_0$ is singular at $0$ and the equation has to be satisfied in $\Omega$ (which includes the origin), so $b_2=0$, and thus $R=b_1J_0(kr)$. Because of the boundary condition, we need to find $k$ such that $J_0(k)=0$.

Suppose $c=\omega^2$ for some $\omega>0$. Then, $H=a_1\sin(\omega\theta) + a_2\cos(\omega\theta)$ for some constants $a_1,a_2$. Similarly to the case when $c=0$, $R=b_1J_\omega(kr)$ for some constant $b_1$, and we need to find $k$ such that $J_\omega(k)=0$.

---

So, then our eigenvalues are $\lambda_{n j}=k^2_{n j}$, where $k=k_{n j}$ is the $j$-th positive solution to $J_n(k)=0$ and $n=0,1,2,...$ . The corresponding eigenfunctions are thus $J_0(k_{0 j}r)$ when $n=0$, and $J_n(k_{n j}r)\sin(n\theta)$ and $J_n(k_{n j}r)\cos(n\theta)$ otherwise.